# python : value error - timedate format error

Tags: python, datetime, strptime, python-datetime

I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: time data 'Feb 1, 2017  0:03 pm' does not match format '%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p'
```

Here is the code :

```
from datetime import datetime 

latest_datetime = 'Feb 1, 2017  0:03 pm'    
datetime_obj = datetime.strptime(latest_datetime, "%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p")
```

I'm unable to figure out why I get the error.

Answer (score 2):

A 12-hour clock has no `0` hour; `%I` will only match 1 through to 12. Your timestamp has an impossible time in it:

```
0:03 pm
```

From the [*`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

> `%I`
>   Hour (12-hour clock) as a zero-padded decimal number.
>   01, 02, ..., 12

Assuming `0` is really `12`, you could repair this by replacing the `' 0:'` with `'12:'` (note the leading space for the zero!):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> latest_datetime = 'Feb 1, 2017  0:03 pm'
>>> datetime.strptime(latest_datetime.replace(' 0:', '12:'), "%b %d, %Y %I:%M %p")
datetime.datetime(2017, 2, 1, 12, 3)
```

It doesn't really matter if you have one or two spaces between the year and the hour, the string will be parsed either way.

Comment: You are right, I did a bad/rushed diagnostic playing on the console.